# How to setup AppRTC

Tags: webrtc

I am using the same code of AppRTC hosted by WebRTC.ORG but still my appRTC does not works.

kindly let me know, what am I doing wrong?

this is my appRTC app: http://qoon.azurewebsites.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try easyrtc.com, an open source client and server with demo apps as an alternative.
If you have any problems feel free to post on our Google Group for easyrtc. You should be up and running in 10 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

At console an error ***`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`*** is thrown. Check the token you are passing at the script. Also you are using js-api of apprtc, so it need fresh unique token every time you relod your page, else it gives used token error. Also the webrtc code is also not initializing, check whether flow of execution reaches to the statement   **`setTimeout(initialize, 1);`** in your code.